# how to auto grow the editable area as you type in CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor

I would like the editable area in CKEditor to flow as user types in more data instead of showing a scrollbar and re-sizer. Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Comment: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the autogrow plugin: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/autogrow.html

Comment: Thanks. How silly I missed this. Autogrow seems doesn't work quite well. When ever it should grow I see a scroll-bar appear for a moment and then disappear.

Answer (score -1):

add a "overflow:h" style to the body in the iframe, you will not see a scroll-bar appear for a moment anymore